# How often is load_user called in Flask Login?

Tags: flask, flask-login

I know the function load_user is used to load a user entry from a database of the developer's choosing.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get(user_id) # DB agnostic
```

For me, it seems that it tries to load the user on every http request. This would make sense since HTTP is stateless. However, I thought Flask-Login allows for a session to hold onto the user until logout or login and the session cookie changes.

**So basically, how often is load_user called, and what triggers it? Specifically, from the browser's perspective?**

Some on my team are observing that the user is staying signed in for too long. I suspect either the session/token is not being cleared or there are multiple signed instances of the same user account as the db attempts to called User.get, or we are not protecting routes correctly with login_required.